# How to make Information icon (popupHelp icon) in Sugarcrm v7?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am trying to make the information/popuphelp icons appear in Sugarcrm V 7.6.1.0 next to text fields.
 I have had these in sugar v6, but they are not appearing in v 7.6.1.0

In sugar v6 I have the following code and It worked fine but when I try the same code in sugar V7.6.1.0, It doesn't work.

Here's how my code looks like:

manifest file:

```
<?php

$manifest = array(
    'key' => 1397052912,
    'name' => 'popuphelp',
    'description' => 'Adds popup help text for question in Opportunities compatible with version 7',
    'author' => 'Swifty',
    'version' => '1.1',
    'is_uninstallable' => true,
    'published_date' => '2015-10-16 14:15:12',
    'type' => 'module',
    'acceptable_sugar_versions' =>
    array(
        'regex_matches' => array(
            '7\\.2\\.[0-1]$', //7.2.0 - 7.2.1
            '7\\.6\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)' //any 7.6 release
        ),
    ),
    'acceptable_sugar_flavors' =>
    array('CE', 'PRO', 'CORP', 'ENT', 'ULT'),
    'readme' => '',
    'icon' => '',
    'remove_tables' => 'prompt',
);

$installdefs['vardefs'] = array(
    0 => array(
        'from' => '<basepath>/modules/Opportunities/Vardefs/popuphelptexts.php',
        'to_module' => 'Opportunities',
    ),
);
```

popuphelptexts.php

```
<?php

$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['f10_c']['popupHelp']="Blah Blah  ";

$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['f102_c']['popupHelp']="Blah Blah  ";

$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['f103_c']['popupHelp']="Blah Blah  ";

?>
```

here's how I want them  to appear.

[image: popup/help icon in Sugar v6]

Would really appreciate your help! Thanks!!